# Is every continuous one-to-one image of $[0,\infty)$ locally compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Suppose $f:[0,\infty)\to Y$ is continuous and one-to-one onto $Y$.  You may assume $Y$ is metric.

Is $Y$ locally compact?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really mean one-to-one? Just include the positive reals into some standard not-locally-compact space. If you meant onto, which is a bit more interesting, it's still false: let $f: [0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty)/\mathbb{N}$ (a topological quotient crushing $\mathbb{N}$ to a point, not some sort of algebraic quotient). The image is not locally compact at the quotient point.

Comment: @aes But your example is not one-to-one...right?  To clarify, I want one-to-one AND onto!

Comment: If it's one-to-one and onto, it's a homeomorphism, because $\mathbb{R}$ is locally compact.

Comment: @aes No I dont think that is true.  If $[0,\infty)$ were compact it would be true.

Comment: @aes: The function $f:[0,1)\to \mathbb{S}^1$ given by $f(t)=e^{2\pi it}$ is continuous one to one and onto, but not an homeomorphism.

Comment: Good point, thanks.

Comment: I think there's a counterexample involving mapping to an infinite product with the uniform topology. Start with $f(0)$ at all zeroes, then on $[k - 1/3, k + 1/3]$ have the image be $(1/k, 0, \ldots, 0, x - k, 0, \ldots)$ ($x-k$ in the $k+1$-st coordinate). Any neighborhood of zero contains infinitely many of these segments, and contains an infinite sequence with no limit point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, here is a counterexample. Define $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ as follows:
$$f(t)=
\begin{cases}
(t,\,-t)\text{ if  }0\le t\le\frac12,\\
(t,\,t-1)\text{ if }\frac12\le t\le1,\\
(\frac1t,\,\sin^2\pi t)\text{ if }1\le t\lt\infty.\\
\end{cases}$$
The function $f$ is continuous and one-to-one. The set $S=\operatorname{range}f$ is not locally compact, because the point $(0,0)=f(0)\in S$ has no compact neighborhood in $S$. 
(Note that, if $0\lt\varepsilon\lt1$, then the intersection of $S$ with the horizontal line $y=\varepsilon$ has a limit point $(0,\varepsilon)\notin S$.)

Comment: A subset of a locally compact space is locally compact.

Comment: @aes I think it is only hereditary with respect to open subsets?

Comment: @bof Don't you want to post a pretty picture like mine ;).  I am having a tough time visualizing this.

Comment: It's hereditary to closed or open subsets. Not arbitrary subsets like $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @aes oh I was confusing this with: open subsets of compact spaces are locally compact.

Comment: In any case, Tom's example below is closed. I didn't read this one closely. Look at my example in the comments above using the infinite product in the uniform topology?

Comment: Yeah mine fails.

Comment: Yeah, this works, and is simpler, just leaving off some of the $y$-axis near $0$ makes it work.